# Htaccess Redirect subdirectory but not the files within it

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I´m trying to redirect some specific wordpress pages to a new page.
The problem is these pages have subpages that are "nested" like subdirectories within this page, and I would like to keep them accesible.

Right now if i do this:

```
Redirect 301 /folder/subfolder/ https://www.example.com/new-directory/
```

it works for /folder/subfolder/, but if some url like /folder/subfolder/sub-subfolder/ exists, it will redirect me to https://www.example.com/new-directory/sub-subfolder/ which is not right

I tried using

```
Redirect 301 ^/folder/subfolder/$ https://www.example.com/new-directory/
```

But it doesn´t seem to work.
Is there any simple way to solve this i´m missing out on?

Comment: Instead of `Redirect` use `RedirectMatch` to make it: `RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder/subfolder/$ https://www.example.com/new-directory/`

Comment: @anubhava This did the trick! Thank you so much for your help